# Why is reputation used instead of the simple common word: "points"?

Tags: discussion, reputation, wording

Reputation is the points of all of the company's sites, and I need them to unlock "goodies" in the website(s). I wonder how it got its name other than "points", and the definition is reputation is:

> *noun:* the beliefs or opinions that are generally held about someone or something.

It seems weird that they replaced the common word for this as "reputation". I want to know because:

- "Reputation" and "Points" have an excellent comparison and contrast about each other.
- The badges on the websites go great with "Points".
- Reputation is like downvotes, like -1, when playing a game, and it is super rare.
- "Points"' definition is:

> (in sports and games) a mark or unit of scoring.

So, why is reputation used as points for a particular unlockable?

Comment: Doesn't the help center explain its meaning on this site? https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: probably first discussed in podcast 4: https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/05/07/podcast-4/ [transcript](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W781)

Comment: I bet your eponymous code has variables like "flag" & "check".

Answer (score 18):

The definition of the word reputation applies here because your [reputation is a measure of how much the system trusts you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). (Thanks to [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361391/why-is-reputation-used-instead-of-the-simple-common-word-points#comment1205808_361391) for the help center link.) It's the system's opinion of how likely you are to use the site correctly.

That said, they're often referred to as "reputation points" and the points you get in a specific tag are called your "tag score" so the terms get used interchangeably.